# Is it possible to use slideUp() and before()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a `<section>` and some `<article>` tags

Right now to return the data from ajax I use

```
$("section#data article:last").before(html);
```

But to make it more user friendly I want to add **slideUp()**

I try this, the data is inserted before the last article but then the last article is slided Up

```
$("section#data article:last").before(html).slideUp();
```

Comment: With out seeing the html, I think you might be wanting something like:

`$("section#data article:last").parent().append(html).slideUp();`

Comment: well that slided Up the hole section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $data = $(html).hide();
$("section#data article:last").before($data);
$data.slideDown();
```

Comment: @EvenJohnson. Sure, just remember that `slideUp` is for hiding with effects while `slideDown` is for showing with effects. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `prev()`

```
$("section#data article:last").before(html).prev().slideUp();
```

Comment: that work but the **returning data** gets hided. I just want to show it with an effect